# How to use nginx(intsalled on docker) reverse proxy gitlab(installed on docker too)

Tags: docker, nginx, gitlab

I installed gitlab according to the official documentation.

```bash
sudo docker run --detach \
  --hostname git.stupidpz.com \
  --publish 8443:443 --publish 880:80 --publish 822:22 \
  --name gitlab \
  --restart always \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
  --shm-size 256m \
  gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest
```

Now I want to use **Nginx(installed By Myself)** to reverse proxy **gitlab** instead of the nginx that comes with the gitlab container.

According to [official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-an-existing-passengernginx-installation) I added some code in `gitlab.rb`

```
# Define the external url
external_url 'http://git.stupidpz.com'

# Disable the built-in nginx
nginx['enable'] = false

# Disable the built-in puma
puma['enable'] = false

# Set the internal API URL
gitlab_rails['internal_api_url'] = 'http://git.stupidpz.com'

# Define the web server process user (ubuntu/nginx)
web_server['external_users'] = ['nginx']
```

Then gitlab cannot be accessed, I found some error logs in this file `/var/log/gitblab/gitlab_workhorse/current`

```json
{"correlation_id":"","duration_ms":0,"error":"badgateway: failed to receive response: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused","level":"error","method":"GET","msg":"","time":"2023-01-25T20:57:21Z","uri":""}
{"correlation_id":"","duration_ms":0,"error":"badgateway: failed to receive response: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused","level":"error","method":"GET","msg":"","time":"2023-01-25T20:57:31Z","uri":""}
{"correlation_id":"","duration_ms":0,"error":"badgateway: failed to receive response: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused","level":"error","method":"GET","msg":"","time":"2023-01-25T20:57:41Z","uri":""}
{"correlation_id":"","duration_ms":0,"error":"badgateway: failed to receive response: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused","level":"error","method":"GET","msg":"","time":"2023-01-25T20:57:51Z","uri":""}
```

Did nothing else except for adding some code in `gitlab.rb`.

I wonder where this `dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080` comes from?

I hope you can help me, or give me a correct demo.Many thanks.This problem has been bothering me for two days

Comment: did you create the nginx and gitlab in the same docker network?

Comment: no, i think nginx is not impotant here,because after modified `gitlab.rb`,error logs shown up

Comment: Ditto. Like @Zeitounator said, entire cluster/services configuration is necessary to solve the issue. A docker-compose file or the list for docker commands that's used in the project would be nice. logs for each container with healthcheck or curl will be helpful too.

Comment: @sungryeol sorry about that,docker commands were based on official documentation and i have added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now i figure out why i could not make it works,I mixed up [**Using an existing Passenger/NGINX installation**](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-an-existing-passengernginx-installation) and [**Using a non-bundled web-server**](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-a-non-bundled-web-server)
If you just need to use your own nginx to proxy gitlab(both of them was installed on docker)
you just need to add two lines to `gitlab.rb`.

```bash
# Disable the built-in nginx
nginx['enable'] = false
# Define the web server process user (ubuntu/nginx)
web_server['external_users'] = ['nginx']
```

and here is [nginx's conf](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#vhost-server-block)

```json
upstream gitlab-workhorse {
  server unix://var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/sockets/socket fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name git.example.com;
  server_tokens off;
  root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;

  client_max_body_size 250m;

  access_log  /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  # Ensure Passenger uses the bundled Ruby version
  passenger_ruby /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby;

  # Correct the $PATH variable to included packaged executables
  passenger_env_var PATH "/opt/gitlab/bin:/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin";

  # Make sure Passenger runs as the correct user and group to
  # prevent permission issues
  passenger_user git;
  passenger_group git;

  # Enable Passenger & keep at least one instance running at all times
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_min_instances 1;

  location ~ ^/[\w\.-]+/[\w\.-]+/(info/refs|git-upload-pack|git-receive-pack)$ {
    # 'Error' 418 is a hack to re-use the @gitlab-workhorse block
    error_page 418 = @gitlab-workhorse;
    return 418;
  }

  location ~ ^/[\w\.-]+/[\w\.-]+/repository/archive {
    # 'Error' 418 is a hack to re-use the @gitlab-workhorse block
    error_page 418 = @gitlab-workhorse;
    return 418;
  }

  location ~ ^/api/v3/projects/.*/repository/archive {
    # 'Error' 418 is a hack to re-use the @gitlab-workhorse block
    error_page 418 = @gitlab-workhorse;
    return 418;
  }

  # Build artifacts should be submitted to this location
  location ~ ^/[\w\.-]+/[\w\.-]+/builds/download {
      client_max_body_size 0;
      # 'Error' 418 is a hack to re-use the @gitlab-workhorse block
      error_page 418 = @gitlab-workhorse;
      return 418;
  }

  # Build artifacts should be submitted to this location
  location ~ /ci/api/v1/builds/[0-9]+/artifacts {
      client_max_body_size 0;
      # 'Error' 418 is a hack to re-use the @gitlab-workhorse block
      error_page 418 = @gitlab-workhorse;
      return 418;
  }

  # Build artifacts should be submitted to this location
  location ~ /api/v4/jobs/[0-9]+/artifacts {
      client_max_body_size 0;
      # 'Error' 418 is a hack to re-use the @gitlab-workhorse block
      error_page 418 = @gitlab-workhorse;
      return 418;
  }


  # For protocol upgrades from HTTP/1.0 to HTTP/1.1 we need to provide Host header if its missing
  if ($http_host = "") {
  # use one of values defined in server_name
    set $http_host_with_default "git.example.com";
  }

  if ($http_host != "") {
    set $http_host_with_default $http_host;
  }

  location @gitlab-workhorse {

    ## https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    ## Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
    proxy_read_timeout      3600;
    proxy_connect_timeout   300;
    proxy_redirect          off;

    # Do not buffer Git HTTP responses
    proxy_buffering off;

    proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host_with_default;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab-workhorse;

    ## The following settings only work with NGINX 1.7.11 or newer
    #
    ## Pass chunked request bodies to gitlab-workhorse as-is
    # proxy_request_buffering off;
    # proxy_http_version 1.1;
  }

  ## Enable gzip compression as per rails guide:
  ## http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#gzip-compression
  ## WARNING: If you are using relative urls remove the block below
  ## See config/application.rb under "Relative url support" for the list of
  ## other files that need to be changed for relative url support
  location ~ ^/(assets)/ {
    root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;
    gzip_static on; # to serve pre-gzipped version
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  ## To access Grafana
  location /-/grafana/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
  }

  error_page 502 /502.html;
}
```

last but not least,you need to add another bash to your nginx's container,

```bash
-v /var/opt/gitlab:/var/opt/gitlab
```

This will let your nginx container connect to gitlab container.Otherwise you will get "cannot find var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/sockets/socket".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are installing a GitLab instance as a custom git server on a remote host. There are 3 pieces of this that must work.

1. DNS setup, remote host's ports and firewall setup.
2. Working installation of GitLab on the remote host.
3. Valid SSL certificates, and a correct nginx config for HTTPS.

The first step really depends on your virtual machine and container's setup, but essentially, make sure it (the VM or container) has a public port that responds to requests.

These variables must be set in the remote host's environment as [such](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/docker.html#set-up-the-volumes-location)

--volume $GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab 
--volume $GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab 
--volume $GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab \

The above URL covers all the GitLab install steps once you have signed in and verified that it was installed correctly and that it runs as expected on that remote host.

Only then, install and configure nginx. Since GitLab likely will transfer credentials and other secure data, you will need to [setup https on nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html).

An example of an Nginx configuration can be found [here](https://github.com/MadhavShroff/nginx-templates/blob/main/template-sockets-nginx.conf). There is also a tool by Mozilla that makes building a custom nginx config easier, found [here](https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/).

The error you show has this URL "127.0.0.1:8080". It is likely you have supplied this URL to the gitlab.rb config somewhere, and that might be a mistake. I cannot be sure without the whole config file however.

Also, it is likely the GitLab image will need to run its own nginx instance, so that the said container when launched may do its job and act as a git server. To reverse proxy this GitLab instance, you may need to install nginx onto your host machine and point it to GitLab Image's nginx.

You may be able to do away with the second nginx instance by appending a new server {} block into the Gitlab Image's nginx config. I would not recommend this.